# How to trigger Onclick event in C++

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I made an actor with a boxComponent and binded the Onclick with a function and I also `SetGenerateOverlapEvents(true);`

Then I created a line trace in my pawn, but it won't trigger the `OnClick` function when I hit the actor.
My functions have the `UFUNCTION` macro as well

What else is needed to trigger the OnClick functionality in C++, Am I missing something?